# Why is clflush an unprivileged instruction in x86?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

While investigating on cache attacks against x86 Intel processors, I fail to understand why `clflush` is an unprivileged instruction.

The only use case of `clflush` I can think of is to flush the previous cache contents before a context switch. But then again, context switches are performed by the OS, which means it wouldn't have any problem even if `clflush` was a privileged instruction.

So my question is: 
**Why is `clflush` an unprivileged instruction? Are there any use cases where it must be unprivileged?**

Comment: It flushes only one cache line (unlike `wbinv`) so there's no need to restrict it.  It's useful with non-volatile DIMMs for persistent memory, so much so that there's now `clflushopt` and `clwb`.  Needing a system call would defeat part of the purpose of memory-mapped [tag:persistent-memory]. And for performance hinting, `cldemote` (write back as far as L3 where other cores can see it.)

Comment: As for the original purpose of `clflush`, IDK, perhaps non-coherent device memory, e.g. video RAM?  But that's normally mapped WC, not WB.  Whatever the reason, it's probably the same as the reason why modern Intel CPUs *guarantee* that `movnt` stores will evict the line.  (Older CPUs didn't, IIRC Pentium-M might have been the first with the guarantee.)

Comment: Maybe it was introduced as a complement to the `prefetchX` instructions. It was introduced with NetBurst, not exactly the golden era of Intel. Back then, persistent memory wasn't really a thing I guess. Maybe Intel wanted to give the programmer more control over the memory subsystem in an attempt to better exploit the new architecture.

Comment: Its architectural effects are benign, so Intel probably didn't see any reason why it *should* require privilege.  Obviously now with the discovery of microarchitectural attacks, we might think differently.

Comment: @NateEldredge: If clflush didn't exist, cache-timing attacks could still use `movnti [rdi], eax` and `sfence` or `mfence` to evict cache lines, since NT stores have guaranteed-eviction since Pentium M or so, once they actually commit.  Without either of those things, having to write other lines a bunch of times to make it statistically likely that pseudo-LRU or LFU evicted the lines you want would reduce the bandwidth of cache-timing side-channels, perhaps making microarchitectural attacks a bit less dangerous, but wouldn't fix them.